# Class Library Error does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have two projects that are essentially class library projects. The first (Net.Data.Entities) contains definitions of the entities I use, while the other (Net.Data.DataContexts) contains the data contexts for objects that my application is to use.

The Net.Data.DataContexts project has a reference to the Net.Data.Entities project. When I build my libraries, both of which are set as class libraries in the property section, I get the following error messages:

> Error 2   Metadata file 'C:...\XXX\XXXXX\Net.Data.Entities\bin\Debug\Net.Data.Entities.exe' could not be found

> Error 1   Program 'c:...\XXX\XXXXX\Net.Data.Entities\obj\Debug\Net.Data.Entities.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

What exactly does the above mean and how can I resolve this problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2012, on a Windows 7 machine, using Entity Framework 5 and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on project select **Properties** and select **Application** then change **Output Type** to Class Library.